# Spring 3+ Hibernate 4 entityInterceptor not injecting in transactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interceptor, autowired

I am facing a weird issue when I'm trying to inject beans,
I'm always getting this stack trace:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class
>   path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'entityInterceptor' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager]: Bean
>   property 'entityInterceptor' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?

When I try to do this :

```
<bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />

<property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />

</bean>
```

I did check `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager` and it sure does has the setter for `entityInterceptor` and my `auditInterceptor` extends `EmptyInterceptor` which implements the methods.

I am not able to get what I am doing wrong in here?

I googled for various ways to create an interceptor for spring+hibernate 4 configuration, I don't want to use envers and I don't want to do this programmatically.

Comment: could you post the class where you using the manager...?

Comment: Make sure you use a Spring version > 3.2.1 it was added in 3.2.2. My guess you use an older version...

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have added right version of Spring jar file it should be greater than version 3.2.1

Note the configuration below:

***applicationContext.xml***

```
<bean name="auditInterceptor" class="com.mypackage.AuditInterceptor" />

<bean id="myDatasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.mydbDriverClassName}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.mydbUrl}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.mydbUsername}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.mydbPassword}"/>
        <!-- Common properties for all DS -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${jdbc.initialPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="${jdbc.acquireRetryAttempts}"/>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${jdbc.preferredTestQuery}"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod}"/> 
    </bean>


<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="myDatasource"/>
    <property name="configurationClass">
    <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mypackage" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />
</bean>
```

***Interceptor Class***

```
package com.mypackage;

public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,
        Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
   //method body             
}

@Override
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    //method body             
}

}
```

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: The question specifies Hibernate 4.